# When to use Tabs vs. Button Group?

Tags: usability, forms, mobile, navigation, buttons

[image]

[image]

https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/button_group.html
http://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#segment-inside-header-headref

My particular use case is a user will have 3 different profile views - a profile for A, a profile for B, and a profile for C.

Comment: Do you want to switch to different profiles in the main view or can you do it in the menu as well (Like a navigation drawer)?

Comment: in the main view

Comment: What type of view will be displayed beneath the profile selection area?

Comment: picture carousel, then text description

Answer (score 3):

A radio button group represents a choice within **the view**.

While a tab set represents a choice of **a view**.