Is there any difference to how users perceive tabs and buttons (button groups) meant to act as tabs?
I don't seem to be able to find adequate guidelines on how and when tabs should be used. Take these variations for example:

a) horizontal tabs:


b) vertical tabs (left sidebar):


I have been experimenting with them all on a web page, and get quite mixed feedback from users I spoke to. I would love to perform usability testing but I am not sure yet about my very initial hypotheses.
Some problems I've stumbled upon are:

some users completely ignore horizontal tabs (no matter which variation) and get lost in navigation - mainly elder ones;
some users cannot figure out which button on the left sidebar refers to the content on the right, even though the active button has different and stronger colour than the rest;
some UX-ers have advised me that "tabs should not look like buttons", but what evidence is there that users have different expectations based on whether tabs resemble buttons (that is, the clickable tab elements are separated by white-space) or just look like tabs (that is, the clickable tab elements are stacked together and the active one is glued to the tab pane - a metaphor of the original paper folders with tabs)?


If there are no definitive guidelines (backed by solid research) on the topic, how would you research that to find out?

Update 1:
Related question:

Best way to show tabs in UI


Update 2:

exploring various UI pattern repositories, I come to the assumption that colour intensity is a dealbreaker. That is, if the colour of the inactive tab is significantly stronger than that of the active tab, e.g.:


I'd expect users to perceive it as a button on its own. As a result, I'd expect them to get confused which one is the active button.
If there's only a minor difference in colour intensity, I'd expect them to understand it's tabs.

Update 3:
With numerous tabs or tabs containing long words, it is nearly impossible to properly apply the tab metaphor of paper folder tabs on mobile devices. (The only exception I can think of, is a slider-type horizontal tab bar.) Therefore, we should seek effective ways for visualizing relationship between button and its corresponding tab pane, detached from each other.

This question is similar to: horizontal vs vertical tabs. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

OMG, how is it similar to horizontal vs vertical tabs? Just because I displayed examples with both horizontal and vertical tabs? My question is about the user perception of the visual UI element "tab" vs perception of the visual UI element "button".

@Danielillo They seem like 2 different questions to me.

@Danielillo This question seems more similar, but still different: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/118311/when-to-use-tabs-vs-button-group

Tabs and button groups and other similar UI patterns have become quite interchangeable nowadays. There are so many websites and apps which use all of them, that most users don't rely on any specific clues anymore, they just interact with the UI, see what happens and then decide on what it means.
I think it's more important to have a clear design language specific for your app, with consistent UI elements that are suggestive and distinct enough from other elements that have a different purpose. For example, you could use tabs for navigation and use button groups for user input and never mix them. The user will learn the UI for your specific app.
It's also useful to check your product competitors and see if they have created a standard in their niche. If they did, then it's better to copy that. For example, if all your competitors are using button groups for navigation, then that's what your users will expect, so changing that UI might create confusion in your niche.
So overall, I think the best solution depends very much on your app design language, your product requirements and your industry niche.

"that most users don't rely on any specific clues anymore" - what is the evidence foe that in terms of published research or personal observations/ personal experience?

"I think it's more important to have a clear design language specific for your app" - that makes sense for UI which is meant to be used repetitively by users (e.g. desktop software), because they'd have the time to get used to my UI, but in many other cases users visit one time only and do not have the time to experience and benefit from consistent design language.

@drabsv For your first question: I don't know a specific research, those are just my basic observations from users using various apps, combined with what I see happening in the whole industry. Maybe this article might help though: https://www.nngroup.com/articles/information-scent/

@drabsv For your 2nd question: Indeed, marketing websites have to rely more on the expectations from their industry than on their internal design language. In this case, maybe quantitative metrics like A/B testing is the only way to know exactly what users prefer.

I don't know if there's scientific research on this, but it relates to the well-known concept of affordances.
Buttons are used to trigger an action, not to navigate content. You could argue that one way of displaying content using buttons is through modals, but it still triggers an action. The bottom line is that users won't expect content to change with a button.
So, when tabs resemble buttons, they may afford a different action, such as clicking for a distinct result, compared to traditional tabs that suggest a more connected or navigational function.
Based on this, it's understandable that anything resembling a button (even a disconnected tab) will cause significant cognitive load. Thus, the only way for tabs is to be connected to the content panel. This is also a skeuomorphic representation of how you browse through paper folders in an archive by selecting a tab. This skeuomorphic approach reinforces the affordance.
As for this:

some users cannot figure out which button on the left sidebar refers
to the content on the right, even though the active button has
a different and stronger color than the rest;

This is because it should be the exact opposite. The selected tab should have the same color as the panel, while the other tabs should have a different color. This is true for most known design systems and frameworks. However, I'd suggest not using strong colors for the other tabs, but rather a dulled-out background to convey the feeling of inactivity, yet capable of (and waiting for) interaction.

"The bottom line is that users won't expect content to change with a button." - what is the evidence/ research about user expectations here?

"This is also a skeuomorphic representation of how you browse through paper folders in an archive by selecting a tab." - how many of computer users, nowadays or even 20 years ago, have ever browsed paper folders with a tab? Even 50 years ago, this has been an activity reserved for office staff, not for the average person.

"The selected tab should have the same color as the panel, while the other tabs should have a different color." - agree with this one, but it's quite tricky for implementation... Let's say the panel colour is white, then the active tab should be white, but then, users should have the expectation from all other menus that the active tab be of stronger colour, shouldn't they? The workaround is to keep the active tab in strong colour and use the same strong colour for the panel borders. Which often messes with the aesthetics, considering all other visual elements on the page.

The first comment: this is even an accessibility guideline. Second: have you ever seen a movie or a comic? Because most people have. Newsflash: many people in younger generations have never seen a diskette or a Bakelite phone, yet they understand the affordance in icons. Third: implementation is not the issue (although this is the DEFAULT in most, if not all, frameworks, and it literally takes 1 minute to change). But never mind, I'm a bit fed up with your behavior. Have a nice weekend.

I know it is in guidelines, but I am asking about supportive evidence. Most UI guidelines, are unsubstantiated. I always take them with many grains of salt.

I doubt that someone who has never seen a diskette, understands the affordance. There's a difference between understanding an affordance and knowing it. The paper tab metaphor implies that a tab and its content pane, cannot be visually separated, as on paper they are inseparate. If some UX designers were acquianted with paper tabs and wanted to convey that metaphor, they would have never come up with tab buttons detached from their tab panes.

I was speaking about implementation in terms of visual design, not code.

From personal experience, I have implemented detached buttons in tabbed interface simply because I had no dedicated tab control.

@Kromster - do you have any research insight how users reacted to that?
